# Problem 5.15, I. Martin Isaacs' Character Theory

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Isaac's Character theory of finite groups book, Problem 5.15:
Let $H \subseteq G$ and suppose $\phi$ is a character of $H$ with $det(\phi)=1_{H}$. Let 
$\chi={\phi}^{G}$ and show ${(det\chi)}^{2}=1_{G}$.

Any idea?!

Comment: what is ${\phi}^{G}?$

Comment: induced character?

Comment: Yes, Induced character.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Can you write down the block matrix of an induced representation? In your case, the given condition says that the determinant of any matrix in the image of the representation $\rho_{\phi}: H \to GL(V)$ is 1. If you try to write down the block matrix for the induced representation, you will see that up to permutation of rows, the matrix is a diagonal block matrix, each block has determinant 1. This gives the result.

Comment: So ${(det\chi)}^{1}=1_{G}$ ! Something stronger than question's claim .

Comment: @imstu0011, no. I said "up to permutation of rows", this may change the sign of the determinant, hence the 2 in the exponent of the result.

Comment: @imstu0011, perhaps an instructive example is the regular representation of $G$, considered as the induced representation of the trivial rep of trivial group.

Comment: @imstu0011, isn't this EXACTLY what the question is claiming?

Comment: "up to permutation of rows" good point! Thanks.